# What is this Javascript "convention" or "practice" called?

Tags: javascript

It looks like *requests* is an array containing uniquely formatted functions and syntax but I'm not even sure what to Google to get a better understanding of it:

```
var requests =  {
  rewardPoints: function(cb) {
    io.getRewardPoints(require.mozuData('user').accountId).then(function(rewards) {
      add('rewardPoints', rewards);
      cb();
    }, function() {
      add('rewardPoints', null);
      cb();
    });
  },
  segment: function(cb) {
    io.getMySegment().then(function(res) {
      add('segment', res);
      cb();
    }, cb);
  }, ...................
```

The code snippet goes on with a few more names followed by a colon like that. Is this an array of variables with each variable acting as a function? Can I call upon these functions by there names like I would any other function? Example:

```
rewardPoints();    
segment();
```

Is there a name for this convention or practice?

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/) has a lot of good tutorials and guides for JavaScript. This particular question seems to be answered in this [Guide to JavaScript Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: Looks like the prototype pattern, but various ones you can look into here https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#prototypepatternjavascript, and you mean object, not array :)

Comment: The lines containing `.then` is JavaScript promises. They are asynchronous functions that is most commonly seen with AJAX calls. Here is [MDN's description of promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). AJAX is like a whole new subject by itself because it involves servers, but if you need it, here is [MDN's guide to AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX).

Answer (score 1):

That's just [literal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), and it is an object, not an array.

> Can I call upon these functions by there names like I would any other function?

Yes.

> ```
> rewardPoints();
> ```

No. They are properties of an object, not variables.

```
requests.rewardPoints();
```

Comment: Thank you @Quentin! That clarifies things.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a Javascript object with key value pairs

```
var requests = {
  rewardPoints: <.. value.. >, 
  segment: < .. value .. > 
}
```

Instead of regular values you have functions as values.

You can call the functions by referring to the keys and simply adding parenthesis to execute the function.

```
requests.rewardPoints // < -- that will bring up the function
requests.rewardPoints() // < -- this will execute the function
```